# Подключение OpenCV к RAD XE6

Tags: c++, c++builder, opencv

Разъясните пожалуйста, как подключить OpenCV к RAD Studio C++ Builder XE6 ?

Comment: А его вообще можно подключить? RAD XE оно ж под дельфятину...

Comment: А почему нельзя ? Можно конечно, под билдер же закатывали :)

Comment: Нужно пошаговое руководство или проблема с каком-то конкретном моменте?

Comment: Желательно пошаговое руководство. Дело в том, что встречались инструкции только под Builder 6 и OpenCV 1.1